# Change complex array element in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to change a value of an element of a complex matrix in c. 
After trying to do, the printed result of the element is 0, any idea on how to fix this?

Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    int size = 2;
    double _Complex **x;
    double _Complex v;

    //Creating complex matrix

    x = (double _Complex **)malloc( size* sizeof(double _Complex *) );
    x[0] = (double _Complex  *)malloc( (int)(size*size)* sizeof(double _Complex ));
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++ )
        x[i] = x[0] + (unsigned long)size * i;

    //Printing the matrix

    printf("Before \n");
    for (int h = 0; h < size; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < size; w++)
        {
            v = x[h][w];
            printf( "%d + i* %d ,", creal(v), cimag(v));

        }

        printf("\n");
    }

     //Changing the value 
     int _Complex t = 1 + 5*_Complex_I;
     x[0][0] = t;


   //Print the matrix after the change

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you use to print. It's not going to help you see a problem when you print the complex, but you don't show us how you're printing it.

Comment: `int _Complex t` --> Sure that is a valid type?

Comment: @TomKarzes `for(int i = 1; i < size; i++ ) x[i] = x[0] + (unsigned long)size * i;` sets the rows - independently.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh, I completely missed that for some reason.  You're right, It's setting them.  For some reason I was imagining `x` to be a row pointer within that loop, hence my misreading of it.

Comment: @TomKarzes OP's approach is less common.  Easy to doubt - as did I.

Comment: what's with all the repetition? `x = malloc(size * sizeof *x); x[0] = malloc(size * size * sizeof *x[0]);`

Comment: @M.M `sizeof *x[0] * size * size` has an advantage over `size * size * sizeof *x[0]` given `int size` - less likely the product causes an `int` overflow. Of course better code woudl have had `size_t size;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After trying to do, the printed result of the element is 0, any idea on how to fix this?

**Wrong format specifier**

```
double _Complex v;
...
// printf("%d + i* %d ,", creal(v), cimag(v));
printf("%g + i* %g ,", creal(v), cimag(v));
```

Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]

**Complex int types**

Such types `int _Complex` may cause `warning: ISO C does not support complex integer types [-Wpedantic]`.  Recommend `double _Complex`.

```
// int _Complex t = 1 + 5*_Complex_I;
double _Complex t = 1 + 5*_Complex_I;
```

**Uninitialized data**

When printing, the complex values have not been assigned.  Perhaps zero them with `calloc()`.  Cast not needed in C.  Perform multiplication using `size_t` math.  Better to take the size of the de-reference pointer, than the type - easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// x[0] = (double _Complex  *)malloc( (int)(size*size)* sizeof(double _Complex ));
x[0] = calloc( (size_t) size * size, sizeof x[0][0]);
```